# Does this measurement for quantum phase estimation look correct?

Tags: shors-algorithm, quantum-phase-estimation

I have implemented Shor's algorithm for $N=15$ from [this tutorial](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-algorithms/shors-algorithm). I understand the algorithm pretty well, but I'm a little confused at the output I'm getting from running the circuit. It appears to be all over the place. The function $\text{qpe_amod15}$ seems to take the zero-th reading and use that phase and extracted period, which has resulted in successful factorizations so far.

Does this look normal or am I just getting lucky?

[image: quantum phase estimation output]
[image: register phase data]
[image: period extraction]]